# DELETE query using form field as criteria asks for parameter instead of pulling from form

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a form (`F_Duplicates`) with a query record source (`Q_Duplicates`). `Q_Duplicates` selects bank account transaction data from two tables (`T_List_Transactions` and `bk_download`) based on date and amount of transaction in order to list possible duplicates for the user to compare. The user then presses one of two buttons on `F_Duplicates` to either run a DELETE query to get rid of the duplicate data from `bk_download` or a button to run an UPDATE query to mark it as not a duplicate (or at least that's the goal).

```
DELETE * FROM [bk_download] WHERE [bk_download].[Import_ID]=[Forms]![F_Duplicates]![FImport_ID]
```

`FImport_ID` is pulled from `bk_download` via the `Q_Duplicates` query. Whenever I run the DELETE query though I get the "Enter Parameter Value" window for `Forms!F_Duplicates!FImport_ID`.

Same for

```
UPDATE [bk_download] SET [Not_Dup] = True WHERE [bk_download].[Import_ID] = [Forms]![F_Duplicates]![FImport_ID]
```

Also, I have to use the Macro Builder as opposed to VBA since using VBA returns an ActiveX or OLE error or something.

I have tried about a hundred different things to no avail. At one point I was getting it to almost work but it would delete all the records from bk_download, seemingly ignoring the WHERE clause. BUt I can't figure out how I even did that anymore.

Comment: This would be easier for you to debug/troubleshoot via VBA. Could the OLE error be caused by security? Is the DB on your local c: drive, and can you add it to the "trusted" list?

Comment: It is in my local documents folder and it is a trusted document.